# How can I modify kendo Grid Column filter option when grid is loaded in JQuery?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I modify column filter option in kendo grid when grid is loaded? For example
add filter option **filterable: { multi: true }** or change width **width: 120**.

More detail, I have this code:

```
 $("#Table").kendoGrid({
       dataSource: { data },
       pageSize: 30,
       pageable: true,
       sortable: true,
       navigatable: true,
       resizable: true,
       groupable: true,
       filterable: true,
       selectable: "multiple, row",
       columns:
           [{ field: "ID", title: "ID", width: "20px", },
           { field: "Customer.Title", title: "Customer", width: "30px" },
           { field: "Author.Title", title: "Expert", width: "30px" },
           { field: "Body", title: "Body", width: "200px" },
           { field: "RemainderBody", title: "RemainderBody", width: "50px" },

           ]
   }).data("kendoGrid");
```

I want to modify Customer filterable like **filterable: { multi: true }**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going along with @NigelK and suggesting to use `setOptions`. Here is an example of setting an individual column to use multicheck filtering.

```html
<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
    grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.setOptions({
        columns: {
            1: {
                filterable: {
                    multi: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is a [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ETagUXAQ) to test the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setOptions method to change the grid configuration after it has been created. Check the API reference for the grid:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/setoptions

Note that this will destroy and recreate the grid.

Comment: I found that setOpsion just modify the grid But i want to modify The Column filter not the Grid.